# Thermal Conductivity Graph

Tags: experimental-physics, thermal-conductivity

This is our first time  (as an engineer) seeing this type of graph that we can't interpret.
This is a rough comparision of thermal conductivity from the Wiki page.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conductivity

**What we know**
The more we go in the log x axis, the more conductive the material is. Say, *silver* vs *insulation fiber*.

**What we don't know**
What the length of each bar presents (in terms of y axis). Say, why *silver* bar is 3 times the *copper* and what does it mean.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the size of the bar just changes to have more space to write the name of each material.

Comment: Hollow Fill Fiber Insulation Polartherm < Water !

Comment: I agree with ffred. Looks to me like the vertical bars for fixed values and the horizontal bars for values with a certain range.